# Android Boolean Change Listener with MutableLiveData

Tags: java, android

I'm very new at Anroid Development and i just want to make a Boolean listener. I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) link to make this. Here is my code but it is not working. What i have to do?

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> listen_bool=new  MutableLiveData<>();

    listen_bool.setValue(_temp);
    listen_bool.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
            System.out.println("hey someting are changing!"+_temp);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You say you are not working but do not give information. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: You register your observer after the event has occurred. If you wanna catch it, you must register your observer before to change the value ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems perfect ,no issue in this.
Just try to put observer before changing its value,it should work

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> listen_bool=new  MutableLiveData<>();


listen_bool.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
            System.out.println("hey someting are changing!"+_temp);
        }
    });

listen_bool.setValue(_temp);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I dont know how to reply with code but i put  `listen_bool.setValue(b);` in the `switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener` brackets. Is that true way to control changes? And its completely working great. Thank you again.